# Display the middle data item from a LLL with ONLY one traversal

Tags: c++

I just have a question about a singly linked list in C++ programming. I am trying to display the middle data item of a singly linked list of integer values with ONLY one traversal. Any hints will be very helpful !

I was able to solve this problem with more than one traversal, but I MUST only traverse the linked list once in order to display the middle data item.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no restriction on memory, Copy all the elements of the list into an array. Finally go to the middle of the array and get the data.

Comment: or copy a pointer to each node into the array ... slightly less expensive :)